# python http web server

Tags: python, http, httpserver, basehttprequesthandler

I have created a simple http server for my family on the local network, when i add a html file and png picture and tried to view the HTML file, my image cannot load. 
It says:

"The image “http://***.***.***.***:255/header.png” cannot be displayed because it contains errors."
Here is a bit of my code

```
        elif self.path.endswith(".bm"):   #our dynamic content
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type',    'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            f= open(curdir + sep + self.path)
            ren = self.render(f.read())
            self.wfile.write(ren)
            return
        elif self.path.endswith('.png'):
            print "IMAGE WANTED!"
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type',    'image/png')
            self.end_headers()
            f = open(curdir + sep + self.path)
            self.wfile.write(f.read())
            return
        elif self.path.endswith('.jpg'):
            print "IMAGE WANTED!"
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type',    'image/jpeg')
            self.end_headers()
            f= open(curdir + sep + self.path)
            print f.read()
            self.wfile.write(f.read())
            return
        elif self.path.endswith(".esp"):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type',    'text/plain')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write("This Format Is Not Supported Any More, Upgrade To BM Script")
            return
```

They all work except for the png and jpeg section. BM script I made myself, same with esp so that is just nothing

Comment: Please tell me this will never be reachable from the internet, because you will have a wide security hole open there (you allow relative paths like `../../../etc/passwd\0`)

Comment: Why don't you just use the built-in `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.  This will serve up the current directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default mode of [`open`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) is  `'r'`, which stands for reading text data and does automatic EOL conversion on Windows. Replace `f = open(curdir + sep + self.path); self.wfile.write(f.read())` with

```
fn = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(curdir, self.path))
if not fn.startswith(abspath + os.path.sep):
    raise Exception('Path traversal attempt')
with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
    self.wfile.write(f.read())
```

The `with` statement fixes the leak of file handles. Alternatively (on Python < 2.5), you can call `f.close()` manually.

[`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path) (for which you may need to `import os.path` at the beginning of the file) is a cleaner filename construction mechanism than string concatenation. The check that the resulting filename is in the directory you expect prevents the [**path traversal vulnerability**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack) that would allow anyone to read all the files on your system.

Comment: I may be missing something, but how does *normpath* prevent path traversal?  My understanding is that it only "normalizes" a path, basically just cleaning it up.  A//B, A/B/, A/./B and A/foo/../B all become A/B.

Comment: @monkut - You use normpath to join the web root with the user path and then ensure it actually starts with the webroot: `import os; root = "/web/root"; path_from_client = "../../etc/passwd"; os.path.normpath(os.path.join(root, path_from_client)).startswith(root)`

Comment: @jdi that makes sense, but it doesn't appear to be clear in the answer here.  The call to *normpath* alone does not protect you from path traversal.

Comment: `import os` is enough to call functions from `os.path`. You certainly shouldn't do `import os.path.join` as that ends with an `ImportError: No module named join` error.

Comment: @monkut @jdi Yeah, you're right. Corrected. Note that just testing for `startswith(root)` is still wrong, since it allows paths like '/path/to/root_backup/'.

Comment: what happens if you request files like member_ph%00txtpng? Do you get must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not Path?

Comment: @Daviddd `self.path` will be literally `member_ph%00txtpng` in that case.